# DBX: Unable to get conditional breakpoint to work

Tags: c, debugging, dbx

I could not get:

```
stop at "<file_name>":<line_number> if (strncmp(<filename>.<function_name>.<structure_variable_name>.<variable_name>, "<some_string>", <length_of_the_string>) = 0)
```

to work while debugging a program in DBX (on an AIX machine).
It doesn't seem to consider this breakpoint. It stops at the line, but the variable value I get is different from the one I am looking for, when it stops.

However, as a workaround, this worked:

```
stop at "<file_name>":<line_number> if (<filename>.<function_name>.<structure_variable_name>.<variable_name>[6] == '2') && (<filename>.<function_name>.<structure_variable_name>.<variable_name>[7] == '4') && (<filename>.<function_name>.<structure_variable_name>.<variable_name>[8] == '5')
```

variable_name is a chracter array of size 9, and is part of a struct.  An example of the value of variable_name is "060435245".

What am I doing wrong in the first instance? The second one is very tedious. Can someone please help?

Comment: Is it actually ` = 0)` at the end of the first code-snippet, or just a quotation problem?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not uderstand your comment. Are you saying put **=0** in quotes?

Comment: `...length_of_the_string>) = 0)` should be `...length_of_the_string>) == 0)`

Comment: Tried. Didn't work :-(